# Opening Print-HTML-Popup from Flash?

Tags: javascript, html, flash, actionscript-3, printing

is it somehow possible to open a HTML popup window from within Flash **and** have it receive text data from Flash which should be printed ... and this all only in AS3 and Javascript (since no server-side scripting is available)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can write a Javascript function to open the popup, and link to it via ExternalInterface.

Learn more here: **[ExternalInterface Adobe Docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html)**

Comment: Thanks Jacob, I can figure this out. But before I start hammering my own Print JS together ... maybe there is an external printing script available somemwhere already? anyone know?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think ExternalInterface will help you doing this as You want to print something which is inside the flash (some textfield or may be graphics). You can use `flash.priniting.PrintJob` and add frames / sprites as pages to the printjob, which will then be sent to printer. And yes, there be default print pop-up whenever you call `printJob.start()`.

Comment: thanks for the hint, but yes it does work. see here... http://cookbooks.adobe.com/post_How_to_print_in_Flex_using_browser_capabilities-11468.html ... very easy actually thnx to ext interface. ;)